# Read php generated XML file with ajax & output to html using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, ajax

I have a XML file that looks to be generated from php (live feed). Basically it contains data that I want to do a versus comparison & output on a html webpage.

The XML feed looks like this:

```
<feeds>
    <level id="999991000" name="Premier level">
        <group name="mix">
            <battles>
                <battle>
                    <supplier id="3000000" name="Stongteam" result="190" percentage="64%"/>
                    <supplier id="3000222" name="Blackteam" result="109" percentage="36%"/>
                </battle>
                <battle>
                    <supplier id="3000000" name="Strongteam" result="198" percentage="66%"/>
                    <supplier id="3000111" name="Redteam" result="101" percentage="34%"/>
                </battle>
            </battles>
        </group>
    </level>
    <level id="9999922222" name="Expert level">
        <group name="mix">
            <battles>
                <battle>
                    <supplier id="3000000" name="Stongteam" result="178" percentage="73%"/>
                    <supplier id="3000222" name="Blackteam" result="65" percentage="27%"/>
                </battle>
                <battle>
                    <supplier id="3000000" name="Strongteam" result="173" percentage="71%"/>
                    <supplier id="3000111" name="Redteam" result="70" percentage="29%"/>
                </battle>
            </battles>
        </group>
    </level>
</feeds>
```

I basically need to display a few things from this file, for example.

**Premier level** 
For battle 1 -  **teamname1** VS **teamname2**
*Result* for teamname 1 VS *Result* for teamname2
*Percentage* for teamname 1 VS *Percentage* for teamname2

For battle 2 -  **teamname1** VS **teamname3**
*Result* for teamname 1 VS *Result* for teamname3
*Percentage* for teamname 1 VS *Percentage* for teamname3

**Expert level**
For battle 1 -  **teamname** VS **teamname2**
*Result* for teamname 1 VS *Result* for teamname2
*Percentage* for teamname 1 VS *Percentage* for teamname2

I assume I would need to use Ajax to bring in the xml data, then some form of javascript to achieve this, though am puzzled where to start. Does anyone know of any references or jQuery plugins/methods I can use and can perhaps point me in the right direction?

Many thanks.

Comment: Where does the XML come from? Is it a user input or do you call it from somewhere on the server side? Are you using PHP on the server side?

Comment: @Quasdunk the xml comes from a feed generated by php I assume as the feed's url given to me ends in .php?locale=uk

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's parseXML would probably make this a breeze: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

```js
var xml = $('#xmlspan').html();
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
var $xml = $(xmlDoc);

$xml.find("level").each(function() {
    var tiername = $(this).attr("name");
    alert (tiername);
    $(this).find("battle").each(function() {
        team1 = $(this).find("supplier:eq(0)").attr("name");
        team2 = $(this).find("supplier:eq(1)").attr("name");
        alert(team1 + ' - ' + team2);
        });
    });​
```

Comment: Thanks @andrew-edvalson for your quick response, you will have to excuse me but I'm a complete newbie at Javascript & jQuery so I am not sure how to apply this, I have briefly tried it but cannot seem to figure out how for instant to determine the name of the level from the name of the team. do you have anything further you can offer?

Comment: Ok it seems jQuerys ParseXML would make most sense to me, I have found an example of how to almost achieve this here http://forum.jquery.com/topic/using-jquery-to-parse-xml-28-11-2010 - can anyone help me impliment this with my particular live XML feed, I still am lost, though I fear the answer is staring me right in the face? Anyone, perhaps @Andrew?

Comment: I attached a very basic example you should be able to build from. This demonstrates how to pull the data out of the xml file and alert it. I assume you can take it from there? I'm not exactly sure how you get your xml into the javascript, I just pasted into a span with id="xmlspan" and read it from there.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely investigate XSLT if I were you!

In a nutshell, XSLT is a graphical layer to your XML data that will render an HTML like page based on what's in the XML data. There is plenty of help on the Internet but as a quick start, I guess wikipedia is not too bad: [XSLT on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT).

So basically, you have two solutions:

- If the server belongs to you, you can apply your XSLT stylesheet
  directly on it and get the result using an XHR (preferred solution because of potential cross browser issues)
- If you don't have a hand on the server, download your XML using an XHR and apply the stylesheet on the client side using JS and XSLT. Careful, our good old friend IE needs its good old ActiveX to make the conversion, last time I checked at least.

Good luck to you and don't forget to geek everyday!

Comment: thanks mate, the problem is I do not have access to the server only the url of the feed, and it is updated weekly so I will need to read from the url feed directly I assume?

Comment: That's not an issue at all. Here is the flow (it is all achieved on the client side):
**1.** Get the XML data from the server
**2.** Load the XML data into a DOMDocument
**3.** Create an XSLT processor
**4.** Transform your XML DOMDocument using the XSLT processor
**5.** Display the result
**6.** Get a snack, a cold beer and show off because you've been playing around with XSLT!

Examples are always better than a todo list: [XSLT example](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp). It shows some good old vanilla JavaScript you can enhance with jQuery but the idea is here. Good luck!

Comment: hey mate thanks! I will have a go at this tomorrow, hopefully you're around to help with the mess I create :)

Comment: No worries! I'll try to keep an eye on the thread. Don't hesitate to +1 this solution for others if it works for you mate.